# Is it okay to use the this pointer?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, this, this-pointer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any reason to use this->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577243/is-there-any-reason-to-use-this)
>   [When should this-> be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491234/when-should-this-be-used)
>   [When should I make explicit use of the `this` pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer)

When working with pointers to classes, I like to add a `this->` in front of variables in a class to make it clearer that the variable I'm talking about is in the current class, as opposed to temporary variables, etc. So my lines would be something like

```
if(this->thing > other->thing)
    this->doFoo();
```

Instead of

```
if(thing > other->thing)
    doFoo();
```

Is it okay to add the superfluous `this`, or would that degrade code readability?

Comment: This is really a judgment call unless it's to disambiguate.  I think most C++ programmers omit the `this->`.

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577243/is-there-any-reason-to-use-this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491234/when-should-this-be-used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Consistency consistency consistency.**

I conisder the `this->` prefix a valid coding style if you use it throughout your entire project everywhere a member is accessed.

I prefer using a signifying prefix for members, e.g. `m_`. I feel it is less cutter and less tag soup than the explicit this->:

```
(alpha-this->gamma > this->alpha-gamma)
```

vs.

```
(alpha-m_gamma > m_alpha-gamma)
```

(The dotNetties have labeled `m_` outdated - I use it on small C# projects out of spite. but anyway, any other distinct prefix would do, too.)

I've seen it used often to help intellisense get in gear, or to specifically filter members - which is ok, though leaving it in for that reason is questionable, especially if not used consistently.

Comment: Most of us "dotNetties" still prefix private members with an underscore, even if we only do it secretly. :-) Microsoft does it themselves throughout the framework. It's so much easier and cleaner than remembering to prepend everything with `this.`, and it's almost necessary in VB.NET where you don't have case-sensitive identifiers (which I happen to think is a better idea). Anyway, +1 for consistency.

Comment: I now do that too for the few "serious" (i.e.  seen-by-others) C# tools I work on. If it's just a scratch program it's one of the very few things I find hard when switching between C++ and C#.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on your coding style, however many people would use

```
_myVariable
m_myVariable
myVariable_
```

To differentiate member variables from the other.

But the most important thing is to just be consistent

Comment: +1 Consistency is under-rated.

Comment: Don;t like the '_' at the beginning of the identifier. Getting very close to reserved identifier names. O. And it looks awful IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

This is a style question, so answers will be subjective.  Similarly, a lot of people I've worked with like to prefix member variables with `m_` to make it clear that it's a member.  (`m_foo` would be like your `this->foo`.)  Then I'm sure there are people who feel this is a crime against the universe.  YMMV.  Use what works for you and anyone you might be working with.

One advantage (or disadvantage, depending on who you ask) to `this->` is that you can have a variable with the same name that can be both a member and something locally scoped like a parameter or local variable, eg.:

```
foo bar;

void f(foo bar)
{
   this->bar = bar;
}
```

Comment: I'm in the "crime against the universe" camp :-) I think I'd rather use `this->` than encode category information into the name. And I hate things like `szBuffer`. Oh yeah, and get off my lawn :-)

Comment: I'd just like to apologize for the ongoing crimes I commit against the universe. I strongly prefer prefixing member variables with `m_` or just an underscore.

Comment: I like the responses.  Something tells me the universe will "keep on universing" no matter what we name things, but I was trying to illustrate that people feel strongly about stylistic stuff.  :-)

Comment: +1 for the Gran Torino-reference.

Answer (score 2):

As already noted this is, mostly, a matter of style.

Personally I do not use it for the data-members (I use the `m` prefix alternative), however I do use it for functions:

- for consistency with templated code, where `this` might be necessary to defer lookup
- for clarity, in order to distinguish at a glance whether it's a method of the class (possibly a base class) or a free-standing function

I think that, since you definitely don't want to trudge through levels of base class when reading up some code, the `this->` clarification makes it **much** easier for the reader. And it's only 6 more characters to type.

Comment: 6 more characters a line keep Carpal Tunnel nearby! :)

Comment: Do you still use the `m` prefix for member variables?

Comment: @StackedCrooked: At work I have to use `_`; for personal projects I have used `m` (or sometimes slipped into using `_` by habit), though it has been a while since I last programmed in C++ at home. Rust has all my attention these days.

Answer (score 1):

I like this pattern too, but I like it more in managed code where it's "this." - the arrow operator does feel a bit noisier, but still it makes it very clear when you're referring to instance-level stuff.

Answer (score 1):

of course you can do it, besides, the compiler would add it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you use `this` notation, when your method arguments and the member variables have the same name. (to differentiate the method argument with the member variable)

Say for e.g,

```
void CMYClass::fun1(int sameName)
{
...
this->sameName = sameName;
}
```

Otherwise, it's just a matter of taste...